# WPF MultiDataTrigger not working

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, data-binding, wpf-controls

So i have polygon:

```
<Polygon Points="1.875,0.875 2.75,13.875 18.875,11 16.625,-3.375 1.875,0.875 "
             Style="{ StaticResource BlockView}"
             Name="KEY_1"
             Canvas.Left="35"
             Canvas.Top="211"
             attachedproperty:UtilityFunctions.IsDualModeActive="{Binding  GetDevice.SelectedProfile.IsDualMode,Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

i want the stroke of the polygon to change based on the values of IsMouseOver property and an attached property which is like this:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDualModeActiveProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
                                                                        "IsDualModeActive",
                                                                        typeof(Boolean),
                                                                        typeof(UtilityFunctions)
        );
    public static void SetIsDualModeActive(UIElement element, Boolean value)
    {
        element.SetValue(IsDualModeActiveProperty, value);
    }
    public static Boolean GetIsDualModeActive(UIElement element)
    {
        return (Boolean)element.GetValue(IsDualModeActiveProperty);
    }
```

the attached property is bound to a property in my ViewModel as you can see in the polygon code.
Then i have this trigger defined in the style resource:

```
 <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsMouseOver }"
                                   Value="True" />
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsDualModeActive }"
                                   Value="False" />
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation  Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke.Color"
                                                 To="#73BB00"
                                                 Duration="{StaticResource controlTransitionEnterDuration}" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.EnterActions>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                        <BeginStoryboard>
                            <Storyboard>
                                <ColorAnimation Storyboard.TargetProperty="Stroke.Color"
                                                Duration="{StaticResource controlTransitionEnterDuration}" />
                            </Storyboard>
                        </BeginStoryboard>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.ExitActions>
                    <Setter Property="Opacity" Value="3" />
                </MultiDataTrigger>
```

the problem is i have checked the values of mouseover and the attachedproperty, they meet the trigger condition but the stroke of the polygon doesn't change.
Any thing i am missing out here?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a property path to specify an attached property, you must also specify the type it's defined in using the bracket syntax:

```
<Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},
     Path=(attachedproperty:UtilityFunctions.IsDualModeActive)}" Value="False" />
```